# Name for this triangle centre

Tags: geometry, terminology, triangles

Given a triangle I draw circles around each vertex. I chose the radii of these circles so that they are all mutually tangent. There is only one way to do this. I extend these tangents. They concur at a point. Is there a name for that point?

Looking at the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers I didn't find a match, though [this](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/tcenters/recent/ajmalf.html) has the right theme. So the 1st Ajima-Malfatti point of the outer triangle is the *point-to-be-named* of the inner triangle (EDIT: on closer look, I'm not sure that it is exactly). And as it happens my motivation does come from 
[circle packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem) from a triangulated graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incenter.  Your construction is an alternative description of the center of the inscribed circle.

Comment: It took me a while to even realise that the tangents concurred at all, please bear with me. How do I see that this point and the incenter are the same?

Comment: ...it's equidistant from the three tangency points. I see! Thanks.

Comment: Also, the three excenters have the same property. In those cases there will be one circle containing the two others, so that two of the tangencies are internal and one external.